# How to programmatically list Python packages on PyPI with certain criteria for example that also have code on GitHub?

Tags: python, pypi

I'm interested in analyzing Python packages that are both published on PyPI and have their source code available on GitHub. Is there a programmatic way to get a list of such packages?

I need to search and filter based on the following:

1. Python packages that are published after a certain date
2. has source code available on GitHub
3. that could be downloaded with pip

I have already attempted to find an API or python package and to the best of my knowledge there seems to be none.

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: List everything on pypi, parse the response, look for github links, ...

Comment: You can grab all packages names here https://pypi.org/simple/

Comment: I've looked and I can't find any way to filter/querying when calling the API.

Comment: See https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/1478 and https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json.html#project

Comment: Thanks! https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json.html#project provides a nice json structure but a dump of all repos is not available. It is also not realistic to iterate over packages one by one as it is heavily rate limited.